How to link a Dll
How can i link a dll? I use windows and minGW
this is the content of the folder:
dll.dll
main.cpp

the a main.dll is compiled with:
g++ -c dll.cpp
g++ --shared -o dll.dll dll.o

The content of dll.cpp:
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

__declspec (dllexport) void sayHi (void) {
      cout << "Hi" << endl;
}

I want to access the "sayHi" function in the main.cpp file with
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

__declspec(dllimport) void sayHi(void);

int main () {
     sayHi();
}

i tried with
g++ main.cpp -ldll

but it just says:
main.cpp:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `_imp___Z8sayHiv'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

can you help me?

You need to use the -L flag to specify the library path.

and for the file name?

You need to specify the path where the linker should look for when looking for libraries.
Here, you can do so by:
g++ -o main.exe main.cpp -L. -ldll


-L flag tells the linker where to look for library files.
-L. tells the compiler to look for library files in the current directory.

